# How can I read Yahoo! Mail using JavaMail?

Tags: jakarta-mail, yahoo-mail

Using JavaMail, I am able to read and download mails from Gmail, but it is not working for yahoomail.com.  I've tried it in all the possible ways I know, but nothing is working. While searching, I learned that Yahoo Mail does not provide POP3 for free users, so I tried IMAP, but it is also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a workaround for this, please see 
http://www.khimhoe.net/2011/06/11/how-to-enable-pop3-in-the-new-yahoo-mail-updated-11june2011/

for No7. Use menu link Forwarding instead of POP Access

Comment: Thanx that was some thing which I dont know but after changing option to POP also it is not working, any other suggestions.

Comment: After changing the the setting and giving web host as "pop.mail.yahoo.com" it is working thanks Komunca

Comment: I don't think it will work now after they introduced oAuth based authentication for clients, even through thunderbird we have sign-in through oAuth , correct me if I'm wrong.